# Algorithm to find the largest number of identical squares that fit into a square with a specified area (ex: 972)

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus

I have a question on my homework that I cannot figure out. 
The question is: What is the largest number of identical squares whose areas are whole numbers that would fit in a square whose area is 972cm^2

Comment: So it seems clear that $1x1$ squares will get you the maximum, so now the question is how many $1x1$ squares fit into a square of side length $\sqrt{972}$.

Answer (score 1):

You will always maximize the number of squares you can fit by using those with side length $1$.

If the big square has area $n$, then the side length is $\sqrt{n}$. Then, you can fit $\lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor^2$ squares into it.

For example.. if the area is $972$, the side length is $31.17$ approx, which means you can fit a $31\times 31$ grid of squares inside it.

Comment: Ah, my bad. Read wrongly.

Comment: Does anything guarantee you can’t place them in such a way that more than $961$ fit? That would be incredibly sneaky, but you never know.

Comment: @URL Clearly not. Considering the projections of the filling on each side, it's possible to improve any solution which isn't simply filling in $31\times 31$ squares greedily.