# Maximum number of unit squares that can be fit into side length $\sqrt{24}$ square

Tags: geometry

I was inspired by this question [Algorithm to find the largest number of identical squares that fit into a square with a specified area (ex: 972)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3460739/algorithm-to-find-the-largest-number-of-identical-squares-that-fit-into-a-square/3460751?noredirect=1#comment7114411_3460751), where OP and we surmised that the solution had to use unit tiles (since the identical squares needed to have integer side lengths)

One question posed toward my solution of $\displaystyle \lfloor \sqrt{A}\rfloor^2$ for the max number of unit tiles that could fit inside a square of area $A$ was:

> Is there some way to fit in *more* than that amount?

So I thought (for example purposes) there would be ample room to experiment with if $A=n^2-1$ for some integer $n$.

I don't know how to begin, and I personally don't think it's possible, since there is neither enough horizontal space for more than $\displaystyle \lfloor \sqrt{A}\rfloor$ tiles in any column (# of tiles touching some $x=x_1$) nor enough vertical space for more than  $\displaystyle \lfloor \sqrt{A}\rfloor$ tiles in any row (# of tiles touching some $y=y_1$).

Wouldn't this necessarily bound the number of tiles to $ \lfloor \sqrt{A}\rfloor^2$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Packing problems are hard.  There are often irregular configurations that allow denser packing.  The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_packing_in_a_square) gives an example of packing five unit squares in a square of side $2+\frac 1{\sqrt 2} \approx 2.707$  The formula $\lfloor \sqrt A \rfloor^2$ would say you can only put four in.  That formula assumes that all the packing squares are aligned with the outer square.

Comment: very interesting, thank you!